# Jquery deferred requests ajax from an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

For 3 days I'm trying to find a way to use JQuery deferred methods in my code, but unfortunately I never find the solution.

I've got 2 functions.
The first one `init_items` send a first ajax request to get a list of items and then, a loop use those items name to send others requests to get ore details about the items.
So in this fonction, I would like when the first request is done, start the following requests.

In the second function, called on click, I would like the system wait the first fonction is completely done (all the requests done) before getting the data.

```
    function init_items(id) {

        $.when(
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                data: { type : type, name : domain },
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'select_items.php'
            }).done( function (data) {

           var promises=[];

            $.each( JSON.parse(data), function(k,v) {

                var code = v.code;

                getCurrentItem(code);

                var req = $.get("get_groups.php", { id: id }).done(function(data1) {

                res = JSON.parse(data1);
                global_news[domain] = res;

                promises.push( req );
            });

            return $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
                console.log('done 1');
            });             
        });     
    }

    $("button[name='refresh_value']").on("click", function() {

        var id = $("select[name='id']").val();

        $.when(init_items(id)).done(function(n){
            console.log(n.num);
            console.log('all set');
        });
});
```

Currently on click on the button, function `init_items` launches but it doesn't wait for the result to display the information.

I have read a lot of cases aboud, deferred, promises, when, but I haven't solve this problem.

Is anyone has an idea ? I would really appreciate your help.

Best,

Sam

Comment: a) you have to use `then` instead of `done` for chaining. Avoid `done` wherever you can. b) your braces don't match your indentation. It seems you tried to do the right thing, but the code you've written doesn't do it. It makes no sense how/where the callback of the inner `done` ends.

Comment: `domain` appears to be a constant and `getCurrentItem(code)` kinda floats in nomansland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.
I've have find a solution. I separated the function in two functions.
When the first has done its request, it calls the second one which launches its requests declared in promises.